# LINQ query for retrieving data from list

Tags: c#, linq

I have List collection of Message objects.

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get only one message with most recent Timestamp for each sender. How do I do it using LINQ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also, how are these messages contained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by n.Senderinto g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: why OrderBy and not Max<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Double>)

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by `Sender` and then get the Max Timestamp from each group like:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(r => r.Sender)
                .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Sender = grp.Key,
                    RecentTimeStamp = grp.Max(r => r.Timestamp)
                });
```

Or you can sort the TimeStamp in group by descending order and get the first element like:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(r => r.Sender)
                .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Sender = grp.Key,
                    RecentTimeStamp = grp.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
                });
```